# How to add DataList to panel programmatically with PrimeFaces?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am new to PrimeFaces and I need little help.
I want to add dynamic dashboard and into each panel add datalist.
I can see dashboard with datalists, but there are no strings in rows.

Thanks for your help

My code:

```
Panel panel=(Panel)application.createComponent(fc,"org.primefaces.component.Panel","org.primefaces.component.PanelRenderer");

panel.setId("measure_" + i);
panel.setHeader(lists.get(i).getName());
panel.setToggleable(true);
panel.setVisible(true);

DataList dataList = (DataList) application.createComponent(fc, "org.primefaces.component.DataList", "org.primefaces.component.DataListRenderer");

List<String> test = new ArrayList();
test.add("foo");
test.add("foo2");

dataList.setValue(test);
panel.getChildren().clear();
panel.getChildren().add(dataList);

getDashboard().getChildren().add(panel);

DashboardColumn column = model.getColumn(i%getColumnCount());

column.addWidget(panel.getId());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use value expression approach:

```
@ManagedBean(name="bean")
public class ManagedBean{
public List<String> test;
//getter and setter of test
...
DataList dataList = (DataList) application.createComponent(fc, "org.primefaces.component.DataList", "org.primefaces.component.DataListRenderer");

//init test on PostConstruct Method
this.getTest().add("foo");
this.getTest().add("foo2");
ValueExpression ve = application.getExpressionFactory().createValueExpression(fc.getELContext(), "#{bean.test}", Collection.class);
dataList.setValueExpression("value", ve);
...
}
```

Actually I doesn't test that codelines, but I used this approch successfully and I think is more useful because you can binding datamodel to bean and doesn't lose control of your data.

Comment: I'm confused... `Test` is a `java.util.List`, Why should it get error on conversion from `org.primefaces.component.DataList`?

Comment: I am sry i forgot getter for another variable and called it getTest :D bad practise to use everywhere "test" .. So it works same as before.. no change. I can just see that there is List with 1. and 2. prefix in rows, but there are no string values

Comment: something like this : `<p:dashboard id="dynamic_dashboard" binding="#{bean.dashboard}"/>`

Comment: Do you run your code on PostConstruct method? Or you run it after some event? Check if your code need some component update and make you sure to put your dashboard into a form.